# Удача и везение

Tags: этимология

Задумался: а почему синонимом "удачи" является "везение"? Кто везет? Куда везет? И еще говорят "повезло".
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2):

По крайней мере, ассоциации именно с глаголом везёт, а кто? -судьба, счастливая доля, Фортуна(римская богиня счастья). Берёт тебя Фортуна, сажает в какой-нибудь возок и везёт без помех к счастью, успеху, и всё у тебя получается без усилий с твоей стороны.

Лексика часто связана с мировой мифологией. И ещё-межъязыковые связи.

В каждом языке свои ассоциации. Вот почему шанс ВЫПАДАЕТ? Потому что французское слово chance - «удача, счастье, везение» происходит от латинского cadere - «падать» . В данном случае счастье - это то, что выпадает на нашу долю.

Если мы вспомним русское выражение «попасть в струю» , то нам станет понятно, почему в разговорном французском veine - это «счастье, удача, везение» . Слово veine буквально значит «вена» Чтобы разобраться, почему так стали называть счастье, обратимся к переносным значениям этого слова. Veine - это не только вена на руке, но и прожилка на камне, жилка на листе дерева - струя жизни. Попадёшь в эту струю - получишь жизнь (кислород). Вот и говорят французы: il a eu de la veine - «ему посчастливилось; ему повезло» , ca c'est une veine! - «вот везет! » или просто veine!